# Why is an attribute of the page undefined while building a form

Tags: javascript, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-forms

I get an error that my this.worldCities is undefined and that I cannot apply find on it with the following code

```
export class SelectCityModalPage {

  worldCities : Array<City>;
  chosenCity:City;
  myForm;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  public appCitiesProvider:AppCitiesProvider, public viewCtrl:ViewController,
  public formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
    this.worldCities = this.appCitiesProvider.worldCities;
    this.chosenCity = new City();
    this.chosenCity.name = "";
    console.log("In modal the world cities are " + this.worldCities);
    this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      cityControl: ['Start typing...', this.checkIfValidCity]
      //cityControl:['']
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SelectCityModalPage');
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.chosenCity = this.worldCities.find((element) =>{
      return element.name == this.chosenCity.name;
    });
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.chosenCity);
  }


  checkIfValidCity(control : FormControl){
    let validation = this.worldCities.find((element) => {
      return element.name == control.value;
    });
    return validation != undefined;
  }

}
```

And my provider is like that :

```
export class AppCitiesProvider {

  errorMessage;
  worldCities:Array<City>;

  constructor(public http: Http, errorHandler:ErrorHandler) {
    console.log('Hello Cities Provider');

      this.getWorldCities2()
      .subscribe(
          (cities) => {
              this.worldCities = cities;
              console.log("in provider the worldCities are " + this.worldCities);
          },
          (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
      ;

  }

  getWorldCities2() {
    return this.http.get('../assets/city.list.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is that the appCitiesProvider.worldCities is initialized when called on a previous page, so this should not be the issue.
Also when I don't have the formbuilder in the code, I don't have any issue. The issue is really appearing because of the checkIfValidCity function.

Do you know where that comes from and how to solve it ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does "in provider ..." print before "In modal the world"? Seems possible that the async call to get the json through `http` could trigger after the constructor of modal.

Answer (score 1):

Methods outside your constructor loses the context of the class, therefore using 'this' will mean the method and not necessarily the class. If you want your methods to use the context of the class you will need to bind it in your constructor.

Add
`this.checkIfValidCity = this.checkIfValidCity.bind(this)`
to your constructor.

Comment: Thanks it works, but I have other methods that use the 'this' like the following:   closeModal(){
    this.chosenCity = this.worldCities.find((element) =>{
      return element.name == this.chosenCity.name;
    });
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.chosenCity);
  } 
And that already worked before :/